# Literature on Principal differential analysis

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, statistics, data-analysis

I'm currently dealing with topics in Functional Data Analysis (FDA), specifically Principal Differential Analysis (PDA). By the corresponding R package description, this is related to estimating a system of $n$ linear differential equations that define functions that fit the data and their derivatives.

Can anyone possibly suggest some literature on the topics surrounding PDA, if they exist? I'm also open for suggestions on good books about FDA that would be helpful and informative.

Comment: I am going to assume you've seen chapter 19 of Ramsay's functional data analysis text and chapter 11 of functional data analysis with R and Matlab by the same author, but just in case you haven't you should take a look at these. I am not certain but I think he coined the term principal differential analysis, I would also recommend his other text dynamic data analysis for ref and of course his paper on the topic in JRSSB "principal differential analysis: Data reduction by differential operators". While I did specify the chapters, it goes without saying that they do depend on prev chapters.